# Can I upgrade my MacBook with more than 4GB of RAM?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, memory

I have an Early 2008 13 inch MacBook updated to Lion. According to this [Apple KB](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1651#link3) the max RAM I can add is 4GB.

I know the OS that came with the initial computer didn't support 64 bit. So is this 4 GB limit a hardware or software limitation? Can I add more than 4 GB now that I have Lion (I understand it supports 64 bit)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add up to 6GB of RAM in your MacBook. You can see the list [here](http://eshop.macsales.com/memory/maxram).

[image: Depending on your]

Comment: It is my understanding that RAM works better in pairs. Since I can't find 3 + 3, do you recommend I go 4 + 2, or just stay with 4 (2 + 2)?

Comment: You need to go with 4 + 2. That's what I've done on my Late 2007 MacBook Pro (3,1). I have been using it that way for three years.

Comment: Check with Other World Computing. http://goo.gl/LzGO0. Confirm your exact model number using the System Information under "About This Mac" in your Mac menu.